# SELECT All Rows that are not Empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want a function that selects only rows from a table, that ist not empty. My first attempt:

```
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max);
DECLARE @Select VARCHAR(3000)
DECLARE @Werteneu VARCHAR(3000)
DECLARE @Tablename  VARCHAR(3000)

SELECT @Tablename = 'AD'
DECLARE getinfo cursor for

SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = @Tablename
SELECT @Werteneu = @Tablename
OPEN getinfo
FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AD WHERE ' + @col + ' IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END
CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo
exec ('select ' + @Werteneu + ' from AD')
```

Please replace 'AD' with your Testtable. My problem is that `IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AD WHERE ' + @col + ' IS NOT NULL) BEGIN` begin although the row is empty.

Comment: Where is the `create function` if you want a function?  And, SQL Server functions don't support dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hi Sebastian.  Since you are querying sys.tables and sys.columns why don't you tell us what you are trying to achieve - there are probably hundreds of examples of working admin SQL procs available on the web for most of what you are likely to want to do.

Comment: This whole thing sounds wrong...why would you want to return every row from every table (not empty)? What is your question? Security does not seem to be part of this

Answer (score 2):

The EXCEPT command can be used to remove any rows that meet a specific criteria.
In some environments the SORT operation can be expensive (this can be corrected with good indexing)

```
SELECT
    ColA
    ,ColB
    ,ColC
    ,ColD
    ,ColE
    ,ColF
    ,ColG
FROM
    mytable
EXCEPT
SELECT 
    NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
```

Here's the code that would dynamically build the query.

```
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(255) = 'Employee'
DECLARE @schemaname  VARCHAR(255) = 'HumanResources'
DECLARE @qrystr NVARCHAR(2000) = ''

;with cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT
        c.column_id
        ,c.name
    FROM
        sys.objects o 
            INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
                ON
                o.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE
        o.name = @tablename
        AND
        SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = @schemaname
    )
SELECT
    @qrystr = 
    'SELECT ' 
    + STUFF((SELECT ',' + name FROM cte ORDER BY column_id FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
    + ' FROM ' 
    + @schemaname + '.' + @tablename
    + ' EXCEPT '
    + ' SELECT '
    + STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'NULL' FROM cte FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```